# How do I check where my code gets stuck in Erlang?

Tags: debugging, functional-programming, erlang, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a function that receives a list, finds the highest value integer in the list, and then divides all the other integers in the list by that value.

Unfortunately, my code gets stuck somewhere. If this were python for example I could easily write a couple different "print"s and see where it gets stuck. But how do you do that in Erlang?

Here is the code.

```
highest_value([], N) ->
    if
        N =:= 0 ->
            'Error! No positive values.'
    end,
    N;
highest_value([H|T], N) when H > N, H > 0 ->
    highest_value([T], H);
highest_value([_|T], N) ->
    highest_value([T], N).

divide(_L) -> [X / highest_value(_L, 0) || X <- _L].
```

Comment: Note that your `divide/1` function inefficiently recomputes the highest value in the list for each element processed in the list comprehension. You should first call `highest_value(_L, 0)`, bind its return value to a variable, and use the variable as the divisor in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For prints you could just use [`io:format/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-2). Same thing.

```
highest_value([H|T], N) when H > N, H > 0 -> 
   io:format(">>> when H bigger than N~n"),
   io:format(">>> H: ~p,  T: ~p, N: ~p ~n", [H, T, N]),
   highest_value([T], H);
highest_value(List) ->
   highest_value(List, 0).
```

---

**EDIT**

One thing you are getting wrong is `[H | T]` syntax. `H`, or head, is the first element in the list. `T` stands for tail, or "rest of the list". And like the name suggests, tail is a list (could be an empty list, but a list nonetheless).  So when you are doing you recursion you don't need to put T inside a new list.

```
highest_value([H|T], N) when H > N -> 
     highest_value(T, H); 

highest_value([_|T], N) -> 
     highest_value(T, N).
```

In your old code you called:

```
   highest_value([T], N).
```

which created a new list with one element, like `[[2,3,4,5]]`.  If you head-tail this, you get this only-element-list as the head, and an empty list as the tail.

---

Also, in your first function clause you have an atom `'Error! No positive values.'` (singe quotes means this is just a long atom, and not a string) which is never returned (you will always return `N`). If you would like to return either some atom, or `N`, depending on value of `N` you could just extend your use of function clauses

```
highest_value([], 0) ->
   'Error! No positive values.'
highest_value([], N) ->
   N;
[...]
```

And you have to initialize your function with `0`, which could be considered a bad pattern.  You could write and use `highest_value/1` which does that for you

```
highest_value(List) ->
   highest_value(List, 0).
```

Or even use a modification of this algorithm: since the largest number will be one of the numbers in the list, you could use the first element as the function initialization.

```
highest_value(_List = [First|T]) when First > 0 ->
   highest_value(T, First).
```

This assumes that handling negative numbers is something you don't care about right now.

Comment: I have made some changes to the code, I could not apply of all the stuff you mentioned. But here is an updated code version. It still hangs. `highest_value([], N) when N =< 0 -> 'Error! No positive values.';
highest_value([], N) when N > 0 -> N;
highest_value([H|T], N) when H > N -> highest_value([T], H);
highest_value([_|T], N) -> highest_value([T], N).

normalize(_L) -> [X / highest_value(_L, 0) || X <- _L].`@mpm

I think it freezes when there is only one item left to check. But I don't know how to solve this :(.

Comment: Still with same mistake, and still I believe that you could find it with `io:format`'ing.  If not, ping me again.

Comment: Alright, it seems like the list doesn't split the list after an iteration. I really don't know how to fix this. 

`>>> when H bigger than N
>>> H: 1,  T: [2,3,4,5], N: 0 
>>> when H bigger than N
>>> H: [2,3,4,5],  T: [], N: 1 `
@mpm

Comment: Something like that; I've updated my answer with little more explanation.

Comment: Just **don't** wrap `T` into list when you call `highest_value` recursively. Not `highest_value([T], N)` but `highest_value(T, N)`.  And that's needed in both calls.

Answer (score 1):

While debugging via print statements is common and even sometimes useful, and `io:format` can be used for this purpose in Erlang [as already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26452641/409228), Erlang provides powerful built-in tracing capabilities you should use instead.

Let's say your `highest_value/2` and `divide/1` functions reside in a module named `hv`. First, we compile `hv` in the Erlang shell:

```
1> c(hv).
{ok,hv}
```

Next, we use [Erlang's `dbg` module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html) to enable tracing on the `hv` functions:

```
2> dbg:tracer().
{ok,<0.41.0>}
3> dbg:p(self(),call).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,26}]}
4> dbg:tpl(hv,c).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,5},{saved,c}]}
```

In command 2 we enable debug tracing and in command 3 we indicate that we want to trace function calls in our current process (returned by `self()`). In command 4 we create a call trace, using the built-in `c` trace specification, on all functions in the `hv` module.

Once debug tracing is enabled, we call `hv:divide/1` and the trace output begins:

```
5> hv:divide([4,8,12,16]).
(<0.34.0>) call hv:divide([4,8,12,16]) ({erl_eval,do_apply,6})
(<0.34.0>) call hv:'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-'([4,8,12,16],[4,8,12,16]) ({erl_eval,
                                                                     do_apply,
                                                                     6})
(<0.34.0>) call hv:highest_value([4,8,12,16],0) ({hv,'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-',2})
(<0.34.0>) call hv:highest_value([[8,12,16]],4) ({hv,'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-',2})
(<0.34.0>) call hv:highest_value([[]],[8,12,16]) ({hv,'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-',2})
(<0.34.0>) call hv:highest_value([[]],[8,12,16]) ({hv,'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-',2})
...
```

First, note that I abbreviated the trace output because at the `...` point it's already in an infinite loop, and the remainder of the trace is identical to the two statements prior to the `...`.

What does the trace output tell us? The first line shows the invocation of the `divide/1` function, and the second line shows the call to the list comprehension inside `divide/1`. We then see calls to `highest_value/2`, first with the full list and `N` set to 0. The next call is where it gets interesting: because your code passes `[T]` rather than `T` as the first argument in the recursive invocation of `highest_value/2`, `H` has the value `[8,12,16]`, which Erlang treats as being greater than the current `N` value of 4, so the next recursive call is:

```
highest_value([T], [8,12,16]).
```

and because `T` is `[]`, this turns into:

```
highest_value([[]], [8,12,16]).
```

Here, `H` is `[]`, and `T` is also `[]`. `H` is not greater than `[8,12,16]`, so all remaining recursive invocations after this point are identical to this one, and the recursion is infinite.

To fix this, you need to pass `T` correctly [as already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26452641/409228):

```
highest_value([H|T], N) when H > N, H > 0 ->
    highest_value(T, H);
highest_value([_|T], N) ->
    highest_value(T, N).
```

Then recompile, which also reloads your module, and because of that you'll also need to set up your debug tracing again:

```
5> c(hv).
{ok,hv}
6> dbg:tpl(hv,c).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,5},{saved,c}]}
7> hv:divide([4,8,12,16]).
(<0.34.0>) call hv:divide([4,8,12,16]) ({erl_eval,do_apply,6})
(<0.34.0>) call hv:'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-'([4,8,12,16],[4,8,12,16]) ({erl_eval,
                                                                     do_apply,
                                                                     6})
(<0.34.0>) call hv:highest_value([4,8,12,16],0) ({hv,'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-',2})
(<0.34.0>) call hv:highest_value([8,12,16],4) ({hv,'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-',2})
(<0.34.0>) call hv:highest_value([12,16],8) ({hv,'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-',2})
(<0.34.0>) call hv:highest_value([16],12) ({hv,'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-',2})
(<0.34.0>) call hv:highest_value([],16) ({hv,'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-',2})
** exception error: no true branch found when evaluating an if expression
     in function  hv:highest_value/2 (/tmp/hv.erl, line 5)
     in call from hv:'-divide/1-lc$^0/1-0-'/2 (/tmp/hv.erl, line 15)
```

Tracing now shows that `highest_value/2` is working as expected, but we now hit a new problem with the `if` statement, and the fix for this is already explained [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26452641/409228) so I won't repeat it here.

As you can see, Erlang's tracing is far more powerful than using "print debugging".

- It can be turned on and off interactively in the Erlang shell as needed.
- Unlike debugging in other languages, debug tracing requires no special compilation flags for your modules.
- Unlike with debug print statements, you need not change your code and recompile repeatedly.

What I've shown here barely scratches the surface as far as Erlang's tracing capabilities go, but it was more than enough to find and fix the problems.

And finally, note that using the `lists:max/1` standard library call you can more easily achieve what your module is trying to do:

```
divide(L) ->
    case lists:max(L) of
        N when N > 0 ->
            [V/N || V <- L];
        _ ->
            error(badarg, [L])
    end.
```